# Z-index issue with CSS

Tags: css, z-index

I need the page1, page2, and page3 links to be hidden behind the #site div. Right now they aren't. It has to be some z-index issue, no z-indexes I use work though.

So the #nav ul ul li should appear behind the #site div. Then when you hover over the "parent page" it will reveal those pages.

Here's a demo of the site: http://tempsmz.hostzi.com/

Comment: Are you about to create a drop down menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the z-index work you should always add position: relative (or absolute or fixed). Also he div that you are covering the links with has actualy got a a transparent background. Try setting it to white and they should disappear like you want.

Comment: What do you mean? I got it working, can you look at the issue now?

Comment: you set all your positions to absolute now. Why did you do that? In the previous version you just had to add position: relative and background-color: #fff to the header div. I had it working in the chrome inspector before i posted my answer...

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property only works with positioned elements (fixed, absolute and relative). Try adding a `position: relative;` to the elements and apply the desired `z-index`, like 1 for the nav and 2 for the site containers.

Comment: Thank you rdcmk, worked a treat. Can't believe I forgot that! What a dult I am tonight, been up all night. Anyway to fix the now caused issue?

Comment: What I'm trying to get is the parent pages to appear next to each other on the top of the page, like this: http://cl.ly/IWgu                  Then when a user hovers over a parent page with a submenu, it slides down to reveal the submenu/child pages - make sense?

Comment: It makes all sense. If you follow my instructions, or PeterVR's, since I gave the answer first, but he suggested the white background (don't know if it was needed, 'cause i tested without it and it worked), you can get it working.